# how to pass API key authorization header to django urls

Tags: django, http, python-2.7, authentication

I have the Api key for all users. I need to allow the user whose api key is authenticated.
curl -H "Authorization:124521021" http://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/rest-api/xxxxxxx/xx/

Using curl method we can send the authorization header.
**Question:**
How to pass "-H "Authorization:124521021" " this header to django url.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply impossible to embed HTTP headers in a URL. HTTP headers and components of a URL (scheme, host, port, path, query component, fragment component) are different.

Comment: Oh thanks. This is helpful for me. i did authentication by passing API key as query string.